# how to download an kms encrypted s3 object

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have created an s3 bucket with no policy and have uploaded a file with kms encryption . I have granted my ec2 instances full s3 access but still I'am not able to download the encrypted file(using aws CLI). it shows the following error: " An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObject operation: Access Denied" but 
I can download non-encrypted files from the same bucket with the same instance without any problem. Where am I gng wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to grant the instance access to the KMS key that was used to encrypt the file.

Comment: I have already granted the instance full kms key access. is there anything else should I do?

Comment: And you're still getting access denied? Are you sure there aren't other credentials configured on the server, in `~/.aws/` or via environment variables maybe?

Comment: yes I'm still gettting the same error message(access denied). Sorry I'm unable to understand what you are telling in the second part

Comment: I'm saying that there are multiple ways to provide AWS credentials to the AWS CLI tool, and if you have configured one of those other methods then it will be ignoring the IAM role you have assigned to the EC2 instance. See the "Configuration Settings and Precedence" section at the bottom of this page: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html

Comment: the conf files show as signature v4. take a look at this document.  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingKMSEncryption.html                    
  in the line below the policy it is mentioned as we cant get or put an kms encrypted object without sigv4 or ssl. any idea on how to use or mention sigv4 in cli. it would be helpful. Thank you

Comment: I think the CLI tool should be handling that for you. Are you running the latest version of the AWS CLI tool?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. @MarkB, could you give a more complete answer re: how to grant the instance access to the KMS key? If docs were good enough, we wouldn't be here asking, so links to docs are only so much help...

Comment: @szeitlin I disagree with your statement about the documentation, tons of people ask questions here looking for a quick answer instead of taking the time to read the docs. Regarding your issue, you simply need to add the appropriate permissions to the IAM role assigned to the EC2 instance, just like you would grant the EC2 server access to any other AWS resources. I'd start by looking at this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/iam-policies.html

Comment: @MarkB It turns out it's not that simple at all. Apparently for my use case, which is cross-account access, I need to add an InstanceProfile in order to pass a specific type of IAM role that has access across accounts. I always read the docs before I come here, and the AWS docs are not completely self-explanatory. Please don't assume all users are the same or that we're all lazy. We're really not.

Comment: @szeitlin you didn't mention cross account access... It helps to specify your exact use case, and in this instance I think it warrants posting a separate question on this site.

Comment: @MarkB Thanks. If I can't figure it out, I might try that. But if all I'm going to get are links back to AWS docs that didn't answer my question in the first place, I'm not optimistic.